# Call Java function with JSTL with enum class as a parameter?

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a java class that I would like to make use of in my JSP page. One of its methods uses a separate enum class as its parameter. Is there any way I can call this method via JSTL from my JSP page?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried already?

Comment: No - I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Best way to figure out how to do things is try to do it.